# Is it multilingualism in India or multilinguality in India?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

I know that *multilingualism* is the ability to speak more than two languages by a person or a group of persons. India is a classic example of multilingualism.

I have seen the word *multilinguality.*

I have searched on google to know the difference between those two words.

I could not find answer for my doubt.

I herewith attach the links

https://glosbe.com/en/en/multilinguality

https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-multilingualism-1691331

Is there a difference between *multilingualism* and *multilinguality*?

I would like to know whether we can say *multilingualism in India* or *multilinguality in India.*

Comment: Actual, the more common term for the ability to speak more than one language by a person is "polyglotism."  A person who speaks more than one language is a "polyglot." (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polyglot) (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polyglotism)

Comment: @BenjaminHarman.You are correct. But we usually do not say India is a country of polyglatism.We can say most Indians  are multilinguals

Comment: Posting this as a comment because I don't think it answers your specific question. I would express the idea using a construction like "India is a multilingual country," rather than with a noun formed from "multilingual."

Comment: @sumelic.You are correct but is my sentence grammatically wrong or is it a matter of usage?

Comment: @BenjaminHarman As a Canadian, I would say that Canada is *bilingual*. Barring that, I would say its *multilingual*. I certainly would never use the words *polyglot* or *polyglotism*, however correct they might be. So, from my perspective, those words are quite the opposite of "more common"; they're very uncommon. I know the words. but I've almost never encountered them.

Comment: @JasonBassford.I think we can say PV  Narasimha Rao is  a polyglot/ a multilingual.

Comment: You would say that PV Narashima Rao is "a polygot" or is "multilingual," not "*a* multilingual."  I mean, we can use adjectives as nouns when we are referring to a person that that adjective describes, like Hillary Clinton did with "deplorables," but it often gets frowned upon for being offensive because it suggests that that's all that person is and because it is so often employed by people who are stereotyping and who are bigoted, like if I said Jack at my office is "a gay" instead of "gay" or Juan "a bilingual" instead of "bilingual," I wouldn't be surprised if I got reprimanded.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman I, personally, would say that a _polyglot_ is someone who has become fluent in several languages through formal study rather than someone who has acquired their languages by the more natural means of exposure. Someone who is the child of a French speaker and a Chinese speaker but was brought up in an English-speaking country would probably be tri-lingual at least but might never have studied any if the languages formally to any great extent.

Comment: I'm voting to close for **lack of research**: please [edit] your post to show what a *reputable dictionary* says is the difference (in both meaning and usage) between the two words. It's also **unclear** whether you want to know the correct usage in *India* (i.e. Indian English), or in AmE or BritE. Please clarify. :-)

Comment: -@Chappo.I have searched on google and provided the links too 0.It was upvoted and  answered too. So it is not fair to close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [dictionary of suffixes](http://www.macroevolution.net/medical-suffixes-h-j.html#suffix-dictionary).

-ism:

> (1) a condition indicated by the stem or prefix (*autism, strabismus*); (2) theory (*neo-Darwinism*)

```
Here's another example: *anti-racism*.
```

-ity:

> Quality, state (*toxicity*)

```
Another example: *equality*.
```

Multilingualism is sort of a description of reality.  Multilinguality is a less common term, and it's more abstract, theoretical.

My children are trilingual and I currently live in the US.  *Multilingualism* is a fact of life for my family.

I sometimes meet people who drool when they learn that my children are fluent in more than one language.  They imagine it would be wonderful if their children were fluent in more than one language.  However, they have no idea what day to day challenges come up.  They are committed to *multilinguality* in theory.  They can't support it in practice because they are monolingual and don't know what it's like to live with multilingualism.